# Does uniform convergence on subinterval imply uniform convergence on the whole interval?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Just 2 quick questions.

1. Let $g_n:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ be a sequence that converges pointwise to $g:[0,\infty)$. Suppose also that it also converges uniformly on $[k-1,k]$. Does $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ on all of $[0,\infty)$?
2. Does converging pointwise on the subintervals also imply pointwise convergence on the whole interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The answer is **no**. Consider the series
$$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
You can show that it converges pointwise for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ to $e^x$, that the convergence is uniform on every compact of $\mathbb{R}$, but it does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

2.Yes, it's obvious by looking at the definition. There is no interval involved in the definition of pointwise convergence. You just look at every $x$ one by one.